# Can you get 1.5 mm DIN connectors for EEG in the USA If you're not affiliated with a hospital?

Tags: eeg

I'm trying to find 1.5 mm DIN touchless connectors that would plugin to an EEG like this one (https://neuro.natus.com/products-services/xltek-brain-monitor-eeg-amplifier). I just want the connector that I can solder my own wire onto. I found one website that I think had what I was looking for, but when I tried to create an account to order them they told me I had to be affiliated with a hospital. Is there something special about these connectors? If not, anyone know where I can find them?

Comment: Consider moving this to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Medical devices are regulated, and typically only sold through clinical channels. That doesn't mean all the components are necessarily regulated or that they can't be sold to individuals, but I suspect *you are trying to contact a clinical supplier*. They're used to dealing with institutional clients, they aren't a retail outfit, and it's probably not worth their time to make a special case for you. They probably aren't even too excited to sell the connectors you're looking for; they're looking to sell whole systems and to provide supporting materials and replacement parts only as needed to maintain their main customer base.

I'd recommend looking for other suppliers, but you may need to build your own or work with a shop that can do it for you.